# SELECT FOR UPDATE wrong result

Tags: sql, multithreading, postgresql, transactions, isolation-level

i ran into PostgreSQL (probably not only psql) transaction race condition troubles. I'm trying to achieve such a simple task using multiple threads:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM t WHERE id = 1;
DELETE FROM t WHERE id = 1;
INSERT INTO t (id, value) VALUES (1, 'thread X'); -- X = 1,2,3,..
SELECT 1 FROM pg_sleep(10); -- only for race condition simulation
COMMIT;
```

However threads are colliding inside these transactions so multiple inserts are executed (primary key collision error). So i tried to use SELECT FOR UPDATE statement:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM t WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE;
DELETE FROM t WHERE id = 1;
INSERT INTO t (id, value) VALUES (1, 'thread X'); -- X = 1,2,3,..
SELECT 1 FROM pg_sleep(10); -- only for race condition simulation
COMMIT;
```

Transactions are correctly blocking on FOR UPDATE statement waiting for other threads commit.

However after "semaphore up" (waking up on that statement after another thread transaction has commited) empty result set is returned from DBMS although data are correctly available in table (from INSERT statement from faster thread):

```
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM t WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE; -- blocking ... then return 0 records WRONG
SELECT * FROM t WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE; -- second try ... returns 1 record CORRECT 
DELETE FROM t WHERE id = 1;
INSERT INTO t (id, value) VALUES (1, 'thread X'); -- X = 1,2,3,..
SELECT 1 FROM pg_sleep(10); -- only for race condition simulation
COMMIT;
```

As seen above, second (duplicated) select statement behaves correctly. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the blocked statement's snapshot is older than the transaction that inserted the new row, so it cannot see it once the lock is removed.

You can see it in the following statement because in READ COMMITTED isolation level each statement gets its own snapshot, so the second statement's snapshot includes the newly inserted row.

You could use REPEATABLE READ isolation level. In that case you should get a serialization error (I didn't test that, so please try it out – maybe you need SERIALIZABLE). Then you have to write your program so that it retries the transaction if it gets a serialization error, and everything should work.